# %1C before file name is causing 404 error

Tags: html, file, url, utf-8, src

I am trying to display the image (for example hello.jpg) and the path to the image is 100% real but it is keep saying 404 to me.

```
<li><img src="assets/img/uzivatelske_foto/hello.jpg"></li>
```

So I tried to paste the path in the browser and the URL changed to:

```
/assets/img/uzivatelske_foto/%1Chello.jpg
```

It was still saying 404. But then I tried to delete that "%1C" thing in URL and it worked!
Do you have any idea how to get rid of that when I wanna load it in the img tag?
Thanks ;)

Comment: I am confused: I do not see much equality between the two shown file names...

Comment: @arkascha Oh I see, sorry. It was meant to be like this ---> /assets/img/uzivatelske_foto/%1Chello.jpg

Comment: I don't quite understand the question is. Is the problem that there's an invisible control character in the source that's breaking the url? Have you tried deleting that line and rewriting it (by hand, *not* copy-paste)?

Comment: Ah, OK, thanks for correcting that. in that case this looks like the URL coded in the property of that img tag may _look_ correct depending on how (by using what tool) you look at it. But it most certainly _is_ not correct, meaning that there is an invisible character in there (a white space, but not a blank or a linebreak), which triggers the described effect. If you really want to reliably look at _exactly_ what is coded in there, then the only way to do so is to use a `hexeditor`. Just looking at the string in some editor or browser view is _not_ reliable.

Comment: `%1C` would be the [File Separator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes#Field_separators) control character – so you have that in there in your code, but it is an “invisible” character. Just re-type the URL completely in your code, and the problem should be gone.

Comment: Thanks guys. I was dealing with this bug for a few hours :D

Answer (score -1):

I added to my PHP code

```
preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $filePath);
```

This will return a string without that annoying whitespace.